# Unable to send files to GFE with iOS Xamarin Good Dynamics Framework bindings

Tags: ios, mono, xamarin

We've developed an App using Good Dynamics using Xamarin bindings and everything seems to work as expected.

However we are unable to send files to the Good For Enterprise App (GFE) calling ::SendFileToGFE.

The call returns true, GFE opens up and then immediately switches back to our app.

As we're also using MvvmCross I wanted to rule out any other factors and so I creates a simple test harness.  The issue is still there and looking a the logs I get:

```
*Jan 24 16:28:50 Dev-iPad XamarinGood[887] <Warning>: [0472.852MB] [056%] [4] InterAppManager::sendFile: allowed 1
Jan 24 16:28:50 Dev-iPad XamarinGood[887] <Warning>: [0472.852MB] [056%] [4] InterAppManager::sendFile:
Jan 24 16:28:50 Dev-iPad XamarinGood[887] <Warning>: [0472.852MB] [056%] [4] InterAppManager::SendPairRequeststartup 0
Jan 24 16:28:50 Dev-iPad XamarinGood[887] <Warning>: [0472.852MB] [056%] [4] InterAppManager::sendFile: pair request sent
Jan 24 16:28:50 Dev-iPad XamarinGood[887] <Warning>: [0472.852MB] [056%] [4] PolicyComplianceChecker::checkComplianceUnlocked
Jan 24 16:28:50 Dev-iPad XamarinGood[887] <Warning>: [0472.863MB] [056%] [4] PolicyManager::policyApplied type 6
Jan 24 16:28:50 Dev-iPad XamarinGood[887] <Warning>: [0472.863MB] [056%] [4] PolicyManager::policyApplied type 4
Jan 24 16:28:51 Dev-iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: Sandbox: Good(327) deny file-read-data /private/var
Jan 24 16:28:51 Dev-iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: Sandbox: Good(327) deny file-read-data /bin
Jan 24 16:28:51 Dev-iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: Sandbox: Good(327) deny process-fork
Jan 24 16:28:51 Dev-iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: Sandbox: Good(327) deny file-read-data /dev*
```

We're using the latest version of GFE and version 1.4.4166 of the iOS SDK on iOS7.  Everything else like http and secure storage seems to be working fine.

To make sure the environment was setup correctly I switched to Xcode and loaded up the SecureDocs example and dropped in the GD Framework, ran it on the save iOS7 device (after deleting the old App first) using the same bundle ID as the harness and it worked fine.

The file exists, CanSendFileToGFE seems to work but the delegate is never called

```
         string path = "/testsecure2/text.txt";
         bool exists = GDFileSystem.FileExistsAtPath(path, false);
         if (exists && GDSecureDocs.CanSendFileToGFE)        
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Attempt to send");
             GDSecureDocs.SendFileToGFE (path,

                 result =>
                 {
                     if ( result !=null)  
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine(result.LocalizedDescription);
                     }
                 }
             );
         }
```

I've raised it with GOOD even though Xamarin isn't supported but if anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated.

I've also got a support thread with Good at https://community.good.com/thread/5287 but if I find out the reason I'll post any feedback here to keep this thread up to date.

Thanks in advance!

Steve